# Access QTcpSocket from another thread (child thread)

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qtcore, qtnetwork

I have created a thread contains a `QTcpServer` which accepts any incoming connections:

```
void Service::run() //Service class is a subclass of QThread
{
    server->listen(QHostAddress::LocalHost, ServicePortNo);
    // server is a private member of Service    

    while(server->waitForNewConnection(-1)){
        QTcpSocket *socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
        handle(socket); // This is a pure virtual function
    }
}
```

in `handle(QTcpSocket *socket)` :

```
// TimeDateService is subclass of Service
// implementation of pure virtual function handle()
void TimeDateService::handle(QTcpSocket *socket)
{
    (new TimeDateSocketHandler(socket))->Start();
}
```

**Note**: `TimeDateSocketHandler` is a subclass of `SocketHandler` and `SocketHandler` itself is a subclass of `QThread` as shown in the following:

```
void SocketHandler::run()
{
    if(!socket->waitForReadyRead(WAIT_TIMEOUT))
    {
        socket->disconnectFromHost();
        socket->close();
        return;
    }
    QByteArray request = socket->readAll();
    QByteArray response = Serve(request); // Serve is a pure virtual function
    socket->write(response);
    socket->waitForBytesWritten(WAIT_TIMEOUT);
    socket->disconnectFromHost();
    socket->close();
}
```

And finally here is the `TimeDateSocketHandler`

```
QByteArray TimeDateSocketHandler::Serve(QByteArray request)
{
    QByteArray response;
    response.append(QTime::currentTime().toString().toUtf8());
    response.append(QString(SEPARATOR).toUtf8());
    response.append(QDate::currentDate().toString().toUtf8());
    return response;
}
```

main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    TimeDateService timedateService;
    //CalculatorService calculatorService;
    //RemoteCMDService remoteCMDService;

    timedateService.StartService();
    //calculatorService.StartService();
    //remoteCMDService.StartService();

    return a.exec();
}
```

In the `main` function I started the `TimeDateService`. But when I connect to the server for retrieving time and date, server sends time and date but when the `TimeDateSocketHandler` wants to close the socket the program crashes:

> ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to
>   objects ow ned by a different thread. Current thread 3998779bf0.
>   Receiver '' (of type 'QNat iveSocketEngine') was created in thread
>   39985efcd0", file kernel\qcoreapplicatio n.cpp, line 494

Can anyone help me out please how can I fix this problem, Many Thanks

Comment: Please show your main function (containing the intantiation and connect). Also, it would better if you did not subclass QThread...

Comment: @LaszloPapp Thanks for your response, I've updated the question post, please see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
(new TimeDateSocketHandler(socket))->Start();
```

The parent "socket" lives in the TimeDateService thread, but the child will be in the TimeDateocketHandler thread. Parent and children should be in the same thread when using the Qt event loop.

Here is the relevant part of the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#per-thread-event-loop):

> Event filters are supported in all threads, with the restriction that the monitoring object must live in the same thread as the monitored object. Similarly, QCoreApplication::sendEvent() (unlike postEvent()) can only be used to dispatch events to objects living in the thread from which the function is called. Here is an example of that:

The solution is relatively straight-forward:

- You could call the method directly with the [invokeMethod method of QMetaObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod). You would need to use queued connection to get the slot triggered in the separate thread.

  QMetaObject::invokeMethod(new TimeDateSocketHandler(socket),
                            SLOT(Start()),
                            Qt::QueuedConnection);

or

- Use signal and slots. This means emit a signal instead of direct invokation and then connect the other thread's corresponding slot.

  TimeDateSocketHandler *timeDateSocketHandler = new TimeDateSocketHandler(socket);

  connect(this, SIGNAL(socketHandled()), timeDateSocketHandler, SLOT(Start()));

  emit socketHandled();

or

- Use a smart pointer (like QSharedPointer) instead of raw pointer
- Move to the socket handling into the other thread.

Comment: thanks for your answer! but I want to handle each socket (incoming connection) in a separate thread to avoiding the server from blocking. Can you please offer me a solution for this problem

Comment: i'm sorry dear Laszlo, i am new to multithreading in Qt, can you explain more the second solution please

Comment: @ABFORCE: done, but you should use the third solution.

Comment: I tried 3rd solution, it got me a error: `error: C2243: 'type cast' : conversion from 'TimeDateSocketHandler *' to 'QObject *' exists, but is inaccessible`

Comment: Well, you have not shown all the relevant code. Naturally, TDSH needs to inherit QObject somewhere down the line, having Q_OBJECT macro within as well as the caller thread class, etc.

Comment: I am done, but when I send a request to the server it does not return any response, In addition the console window logs 'QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method TimeDateSocketHandler::1Start()()'

Comment: Well, of course, if you make a typo with a '1' before the "Start" name.

Comment: no no, i exactly copy and paste your code in my project and there is no any `1` in the name of method

Comment: It is possible that you made a copy/paste error and/or accidentally modified the line. Otherwise, Start() has to be a slot obviously.

Comment: @ABFORCE: did you get it working after adding "public slots" to Start() in the corresponding header?

Comment: finally I could solve this problem by creating client socket in the new thread (like threaded fortune server example of Qt). Many thanks sir for spending your time for me. Can you add this alternative to your answer and then I accepting it

Comment: @ABFORCE: done, but invokeMethod should have worked, too. :-)